# Subtype Supertype with Oracle Object Type Creation. Limit on the number of subtypes?

Tags: oracle, object, oracle10g, subtype, supertype

I have run into an issue when creating a object type in Oracle 10g that inherits from a supertype. We currently have many object types that inherit from this supertype and recently the compiler started throwing the following errors

`ORA-30745: error occured while trying to add column "SYS_NC_ROWINFO$" in table "DATA_CACHE.CACHE_ENTRIES"`

`ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000`

Is there a cap on the number of subtypes you can generate that inherit from a supertype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create tables with columns based on user-defined types, Oracle creates additional "secret" columns for you under the covers.  For example:

```
SQL> create type emp_data_t  as object (empno number, ename varchar2(30));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table emp_data_table (id int, emp_data emp_data_t);

Table created.
```

This table **appears** to have 2 columns:

```
SQL> desc emp_data_table
 Name                       Null?    Type
 -------------------------- -------- ------------------------
 ID                                  NUMBER(38)
 EMP_DATA                            EMP_DATA_T
```

... but it **really** has four:

```
SQL> select name
  2  from sys.col$
  3  where obj# = (select object_id 
  4                from user_objects 
  5                where object_name='EMP_DATA_TABLE');

NAME
------------------------------
ID
EMP_DATA
SYS_NC00003$
SYS_NC00004$
```

As you have seen, Oracle has a limit of 1000 columns per table.  This limit will include any of these hidden columns derived from types and supertypes.  It looks like your table has exceeded this limit.

Answer (score -1):

use command:

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```